# When using glOrthof, all I see is a cross

Tags: c, ios, opengl-es, landscape, aspect-ratio

I have an iOS app which runs in landscape (always), and uses OpenGL for drawing. I have this code in my draw method:

```
  GLfloat width = self.frame.size.width;   // 480
  GLfloat height = self.frame.size.height; // 320
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrthof(-width / 2, width / 2, -height / 2, height / 2, -1.0f, 1.0f);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glTranslatef(160.0f, 240.0f, 0.0f);
  glRotatef(-90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glTranslatef(self.player.x, self.player.y, 0.0f);
```

Where `self.player.x` and `self.player.y` are `GLfloat` variables ranging from `-3.0f` to `3.0f`.

However, all I see is a blue cross:
[image: screenshot]

I use `glOrthof` to make OpenGL use the correct aspect ratio. When I comment the `glOrthof` call out, I get this result (the light blue lines should form squares, not rectangles):
[image: half-good]

---

I tried everything, from swapping the width and the height, changing the parameters of the `glOrthof` call, but nothing helped. Could someone help me out, or explain what I've done wrong? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
GLfloat aspect=width/height;
glOrthof(-aspect, aspect, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0f, 1.0f);
```